# Fedora Core 10: Window List & Workspace Switcher applets keep crashing

Tags: linux, fedora, taskbar

I was minding my own business typing a command or two in a Terminal window when a dialog popped up telling me that the Workspace Switcher had crashed, and would I like to reload.  Without thinking I clicked the default "Don't Reload" button, and promptly saw two other windows reporting that both the Window List and Window Selector applets had also crashed.  As soon as I add one of them to a panel, they promptly crash.  Here are some of the crash reports -- I repeatedly see the same complaints:

The first is a Python traceback complaining that it can't load cups.  Cups is installed, and I can load it using /usr/bin/python

Another complaint is a Bonobo warning that it got:

> Unknown CORBA exception id: 'IDL:omg.org/CORBA/COMM_FAILURE:1.0'

Here's another one:

> panel-applet-frame.c:1285: failed to load applet OAFIID:GNOME_WindowListApplet: System exception: IDL:omg.org/CORBA/COMM_FAILURE:1.0

I suppose I could always repave the system, and try a newer version of Fedora Core (I had problems building our software under both versions 11 and 12 last time I had to upgrade, so I stuck with 10). But I'd rather fix this, if anyone knows...

This happens when I start up Firefox (3.6).  I'd like to have it up and running
though -- makes it easier to intergrate checkin messages and bug tracking reports.

Comment: A workaround is to regress to Firefox 3.6.3.  Now my workspace is stable. TFATH